# Conducting Calculation on Selected Task's Custom Field Upon Change Event

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am wondering whether it is possible to create a script that runs a calculation for a selected task's field after a change event. I currently have a script that runs calculations for every task in my ms project file. I want to move away from this method by implementing code that isolates a task and computes a respective value.

Can someone please let me know if this is possible?

I do not have a bock of code at the moment because I have been struggling on where to start. I have referenced this thread ([Microsoft Project VBA to update Custom field on task change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908824/microsoft-project-vba-to-update-custom-field-on-task-change)) but have not been able to implement it with success.

My cm_Events class module:

```
Public WithEvents MyMSPApp As MSProject.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

Set MyMSPApp = Application

End Sub

Private Sub MyMSPApp_ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange(ByVal Assgn As      Assignment, ByVal Field As PjField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

If EnableEvents Then
    EnableEvents = False

Dim X As Integer
X = 5
Debug.Print X
    

    EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

My m_Events Module:

```
Public oMSPEvents As New cm_Events
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Sub StartEvents()

Set oMSPEvents.MyMSPApp = Application ' MSProject.Application
EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

My Project Code Block:

```
Private Sub Project_Open(ByVal pj As Project)

Call m_Events.StartEvents

End Sub
```

What I Would Place Into Before Assignment Change Script:

```
    tsk.Cost5 = 0

    Dim Assgn As Assignment
    For Each Assgn In tsk.Assignments
        If Assgn.Resource.Text1 = "Labor" Then
            tsk.Cost5 = tsk.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
            Assgn.Cost5 = Assgn.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
        End If
    Next Assgn
```

Comment: To be clear, you want some method that will perform some kind of calculation on a selected task only when a change is made to a field of that task?

Comment: I'm sure your code can be modified to act on one isolated task... but I'd suggest you actually post what code you have if you want someone to look at it.

Comment: @KennyArnold, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @CameronCritchlow, I will upload my code now. There are two scripts where I would like to apply this methodology. I will upload the less complex script first.

Comment: @BP130 do you want this to just work for one particular projects or be universal for all projects you work on?

Comment: @BP130 Please elaborate on "have not been able to implement it with success" regarding using the ProjectBeforeTaskChange event. Also, `tsk.Cost5 = tsk.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost` looks problematic as Cost5 will increase with every change to the task, unless the purpose of Cost5 is to keep track of the number of changes, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, I was showing this block of code as an example of the functionality I have already achieved. The function you snipped helps to pull cost data off of resource loads and shows it at the task level. More explicitly, the code looks back to the resource sheet to determine whether a resource fits the criterion for "labor". If it meets this criteria, the script loads the assigment cost into the task cost so I could view it in the gantt chart.

Comment: @KennyArnold, it would be great to create a script that I could tailor to any project.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, I added a code block for the solution I tried based on my lessons learned from the ProjectBeforeTaskChange event.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, I could not seem to get the code (on a task change event) to execute the code I left in the second example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will track costs for Labor resources using the Cost5 field and will update automatically when either the task or the assignment is updated, using the respective event handlers.

For the **cm_Events** *class* module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyMSPApp As MSProject.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set MyMSPApp = Application

End Sub

Private Sub MyMSPApp_ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange(ByVal asg As Assignment, ByVal Field As PjAssignmentField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    If EnableEvents Then
        EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim tsk As Task
        Set tsk = asg.Task
        tsk.Cost5 = 0
        UpdateCost5 tsk
        
        EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub MyMSPApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(ByVal tsk As Task, ByVal Field As PjField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    If EnableEvents Then
        EnableEvents = False
    
        tsk.Cost5 = 0
        UpdateCost5 tsk
    
        EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCost5(tsk As Task)
       
    tsk.Cost5 = 0
 
    Dim Assgn As Assignment
    For Each Assgn In tsk.Assignments
        If Assgn.Resource.Text1 = "Labor" Then
            tsk.Cost5 = tsk.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
            Assgn.Cost5 = Assgn.Cost
          Else
            Assgn.Cost5 = 0
        End If
    Next Assgn
        
End Sub
```

For the **m_Events** module:

```
Public oMSPEvents As New cm_Events
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Sub StartEvents()

    Set oMSPEvents.MyMSPApp = Application ' MSProject.Application
    EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

For the **ThisProject** module:

```
Private Sub Project_Open(ByVal pj As Project)

    Call m_Events.StartEvents

End Sub
```

**Tips:**

- make sure **cm_Events** is a class module and not a regular module.
- any time you make a change to the code the events will stop running--always run the **StartEvents** procedure after making any changes.
- Start with simple code in the ProjectBeforeTaskChange event like a debug statement to verify the event is getting triggered.
- the *TaskChange* event is just that--triggered by changes to the task, but not to a resource or assignment.

Comment: would you be open to briefly explaining how these blocks of code work together to calculate and place a value in Cost5? Also, would you be open to providing a few steps to follow to execute an example? This is my first time implementing code like this and I think I am messing it up somehow.

Comment: @BP130 I added some tips & a sample debug statement in the event procedure.

Comment: This is extremely helpful for my understanding - thanks! What if the primary change I plan on making is to the resource assignments? Can replace taskchange with assignmentchange without much difficultly? Essentially, I am trying to pull labor costs into a separate column (i.e., Cost5) without having to run my long script that iterates through each assignment on every task. I may change resource1 units from 2 to 3 and want to see the uptick in cost funnel into Cost5.

Comment: I replaced taskchange with assignemnt change and updated the input to an assignment data type. I am receiving a compile error. It states, " Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".

Comment: @BP130 see edits above. BTW to add other event handlers, select them from the upper right drop-down list in the class module (be sure cursor is in the Initialize event or lower first).

Comment: your solution got me to the next phase of my problem solving journey! Thank you very much for the help. Would you be open to checking out my new post to see if you can guide me a little bit further?