# Custom event with VBA in ms Project

Tags: excel, vba, project, ms-project

I'm working on Microsoft Projects and each of my tasks have a project ID. No two tasks should have the same project ID and the project ID has a format it must follow.

(For example the format is "ID5679", so each ID starts with the letters I and D and then a combination of four numbers)

I'm trying to find a way, so that every time someone adds a Task row, the macro runs and automatically writes an ID, that hasn't been used before, in the ID column.

I have some experience working with excel VBA but I'm new to project VBA and quite confused.

I'm struggling on how to make a custom worksheet event, so that the macro runs ever time someone adds a task row and the program froze and crashed.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! (Any resources for vba in ms project would also be extremely helpful!)

Comment: Why not use the Task Unique ID field which is exactly that and already built in?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see Rachel's response before I typed mine but I also say, why not just us the Unique ID field. Also, you talk about Project and "worksheet event". Are you trying to write something that is interactive between Project and Excel?

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses! No I'm not trying to make a something interactive between project and excel, I'm just not used to the project interface and I mistakenly used excel terms. The problem is that you can't customize the unique ID field (as far as I know) and the Id's that I need are a very specific format cause they correlate with the company files that also follow the same format.

Comment: Look at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Devent), especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250929/conducting-calculation-on-selected-tasks-custom-field-upon-change-event).